# Ulam stability of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $P$ be  a homogenous  polynomial with real coefficients in several variable(at least three variable)
Is the following statement true:

> For every $\epsilon$ there is  a $\delta$ such that for every x with $|P(x)|< \delta$ we have $d(x,Z)<\epsilon$.

Here $Z=P^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the set of roots of $P$, and $d$ is the standard .distance

Comment: To me this question feels garbled (my fault?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT. My previous answer was incorrect. So I replace it.
The answer is no. A counterexample is
$$y^{2m}+(z^{m-1}y-x^m)^2.$$
This is of degree $2m$ but $\delta$ is like $\epsilon^{2m^2}$ near the
point $(0,0,1)$.

I found this example in the paper of Kollar and Shiffman, TAMS 329 (1992), on the very first page. They credit it to Lojasiewicz himself, IHES, Bures-sur-Yvette, 1965.
I do not know how to find this IHES preprint, but Kollar and Shiffman is available
to everyone online.

Comment: Thank you. But i think that some thing is missing.Let the degree of polynomial is n. Then we need to know, on the unit spher, \delta is in the for O(\epslon^{n})

Comment: I think that the order power in Lojasiewicz type inequalities is sensitive in this question. So do you think that the Ulam stability of  homogeneous polynomials in at least 3 variables can be solved with other approaches? however in 2 variable the subject is obvious because of factorization to polynomials with low(1 or 2) degree